# Take out a specific part of string through powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a string named "abcd_xyz_6.0.1"
I want to take out 6.0.1 of that string and use it somewhere else.
I want to do it with -replace() operator in powershell.
Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

`-replace` uses *regex*, so just replace everything (greedy) until the last underscore:

```
'abcd_xyz_6.0.1' -replace '.*_'
```

Comment: It replaces the first underscore. Isn't that being greedy or have I misunderstood the concept of greediness?

Comment: It replaces everything except 6.0.1 - but you are right, it is greedy :-)